# How can I make the nested table align on top?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularray

How can I make the nested table align on top? I have tried everything but tabularray alignment are really annoying.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec = { X[c,h] Q[c,h,wd=10pt] *{6}{X[c,h,2cm]} },
  width = \textwidth,
  hlines,
  vlines,
}
& \SetCell[c=4]{h}  \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={ccc},
        hlines,
        }
& A & B & C \\
& A & B & C \\
& A & B & C \\
& A & B & C \\
\end{tblr}  & & & & \SetCell[c=3]{h} \includegraphics[]{example-image-a} & & & \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the correct baselines. It's easier with `tabularray` because the package has a keyword `baseline` just for it. However you need `adjustbox` to change baseline for images, with some small adjustment (see `\adjboxvtop`). Depending on what is in the first column, try to swap `Q` column with `X`:

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\renewcommand{\adjboxvtop}{\baselineskip}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec = {Q[wd=2cm] X[c] X[3]},
    width = \textwidth,
    hlines,
    vlines,
  }
  & \begin{tblr}{
      baseline=T,
      colspec={ccc},
      hlines,
    }
    & A & B & C \\
    & A & B & C \\
    & A & B & C \\
    & A & B & C \\
  \end{tblr}
  & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} \\
  & \begin{tblr}{
      baseline=T,
      colspec={ccc},
      hlines,
    }
    & A & B & C \\
    & A & B & C \\
    & A & B & C \\
    & A & B & C \\
  \end{tblr}
  & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b} \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]